# How to Store Conversation reference(dictionary) into Azure DB Storage

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

Im working on a bot with Bot framework v4 in  nodejs.
I want my Conversation reference for every user to be stored into an azure db.
Conversation reference is in a nested dictionary format. {'convid':{"a":'value","b":"value"}}

I want this dictionary to be stored in Azure DB (Which Db would be suitable?free version?Paid?) so that i could later retrieve this DB and send out a proactive messages to all users whose conv ref is stored.

I just want to know how to store dictionary into any azure DB with node js?
and retrieve it later? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving the conversation reference during a (private) conversation can be achieved using the following snippet.

```js
conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);
```

You can eventually save this JSON directly to CosmosDB using the [Cosmos Javascript SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/cosmos).

```js
const databaseDefinition = { id: "sample database" };
const collectionDefinition = { id: "sample collection" };

const { database } = await client.databases.create(databaseDefinition);
const { container } = await database.containers.create(collectionDefinition); 

const { resource } = await container.items.create(conversationReference);
```

Comment: Also in the above logic ,would it keep appending the resource.as more no of users chat with the bot.... later i would need to retrieve the resource and check for a particular conversation id existing in the database directly using an if condition directly. i.e if(resource('convid') exists) instead of looping all the convid's stored in resources and comparing where that covid is present or not.

Comment: Also Mick the given code is SQL API over of the cosmo's db i believe it works really well over JSON. My azure account already has a cosmo db ,where  Mongo API is being used. Would adding a SQL API over it cost additional charges?

Comment: You could also use a Mongo SDK to write to your existing Mongo API containers, if you know how to use Mongo! By the way, [CosmosDB also offers a free tier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/build-apps-for-free-with-azure-cosmos-db-free-tier/) nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. just one more question. i was using const conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences) in the code to retrieve all the users whom had an iteraction with the bot later to send a proactive message to them.I noticed that ,whenever the server is restarted ,no users are saved. Which would mean conversation references are erased from memory. In production would this logic work since there wouldn't be any server refresh?

Comment: @sree saving conversationReferences in memory is a bad practice in production. What if you need to scale out (multiple servers)? And in production, servers could also be restarted for updates and configuration changes. Your application state is something you would need to persist in a database.

Comment: i see thanks for all the replies. I was more interested in SQL API over json because in the logic i need to check for Conversation id's whether already stored and then save it if not. Using mongo db would require checking all the convid's one by one which isn't practically since the no of user would be more than 10k. Is there any other workaround ? Or something like Select * from table where convid='existing; is the best choice.

Comment: @Mick can you please provide equivalent code for c#. Also how do we get those value in notify controller? Currently my dictionary is getting stored into the local memory I think because when my bot application pool is recycled all conversation reference for all users is lost. Kindly help me with this. I tried and gone through many link but not found the solution for it.

Comment: @nil, I don't know if you later found the C# code to retrieve the ConversationReference values? In case you haven't, [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages/Controllers/NotifyController.cs) implements proactive messages where you can retrieve the ConversationReference values in the notify controller.

Answer (score 0):

@Sree - You can pull all the conversation using [Graph API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-conversation?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) please check the documents. If you have requirement to store data in dictionary only, you can explore [Cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction). 
Please check [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/sql-database/managed/).

Comment: Could i use Blob Storage to Save dictionary's??